# Trouble with setting a $scope value with a ng-repeat - value is not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I seem to have some trouble with setting a `$scope` value with a `ng-repeat`

Here are my $scope variables in my controller

```
    $scope.selectedDate = "25.04.2014";
    $scope.availableDates = [
{"date":"25.04.2014","day":"Fri", "hasDiscount":false},
{"date":"26.04.2014","day":"Sat", "hasDiscount":false},
{"date":"27.04.2014","day":"Sun", "hasDiscount":false},
{"date":"28.04.2014","day":"Mon", "hasDiscount":false}
];
```

Here is the repeat in my HTML view:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 no-padding" data-ng-repeat="days in availableDates">
    <div
        class="square-but"
        data-ng-click="selectedDate = days.date"
        data-ng-class="{ 'date-choice-selected': selectedDate === days.date }">
        <span>{{ days.day }}</span>
        <span>{{ days.date.substring(0, days.date.length - 5) }}</span>
        <div class="discount" data-ng-show="days.hasDiscount"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This outputs the necessary information, however when I click on the different divs I have noticed that the `date-choice-selected` class is added by the `ng-class` but it is not deselected on the previously selected div/date. The reason for this is that the `$scope.selectedDate` doesn't seem to be updated by the ng-click, when I try to output this to the interface using `{{ selectedDate }}` the value doesn't change, it always remains as 25.04.2014! I have also have a `$watch` on this item like so:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedDate', function () {
    console.log('selectedDate Change');
    $scope.someHttpThing();
});
```

But this `$watch` is never triggered / called when clicking the child Div. What am I doing wrong? Does the `ng-repeat` introduce a new $scope? Do I need to `$broadcast` / `$emit`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [**ngRepeat**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) create its own scope, You should use `$parent.selectedDate` instead of `selectedDate` in HTML.

From [**ngRepeat**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) docs (Emphasis mine)

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets **its own scope**.

*Code*

```
<div class="col-xs-2 no-padding" data-ng-repeat="days in availableDates">
    <div
        class="square-but"
        data-ng-click="$parent.selectedDate = days.date"
        data-ng-class="{ 'date-choice-selected': $parent.selectedDate === days.date }">
        <span>{{ days.day }}</span>
        <span>{{ days.date.substring(0, days.date.length - 5) }}</span>
        <div class="discount" data-ng-show="days.hasDiscount"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/B6e9K/2/)

Comment: I think I love you! So the ng-repeat adds a child $scope?

Comment: @MikeSav, ngRepeat create its own scope

Comment: Better to stay away from `$parent`. Make your `selectedDate` into an object `{selectedDate:null}` and then do binding, using the `.` notation.